# iOS Universal Link- Opening the App right away from the email

Tags: ios, react-native

I've implemented handling Universal Links in my React Native project and it seems to be working fine, however, the problem I have is that when the user clicks in the link in his Gmail app on iOS, a popup shows up with a list of browsers:

[image]

And then, it redirects to my app only if the user clicks 'Default browser app'. If he clicks Safari, it opens a website instead. I've checked how other apps do it, and Spotify has it set up the same way, however, LinkedIn opens the app right away, without even showing up a list of browsers. What I would like to achieve is either LinkedIn behavior, or so the app is opened as well when the user clicks on Safari.

For reference, I followed standard steps listed for example here: https://rossbulat.medium.com/deep-linking-in-react-native-with-universal-links-and-url-schemes-7bc116e8ea8b

Added my URL to types, to Associated Domains, Added AASA to my website (with accepting all paths) and modified iOS appDelegate file.

Comment: any success on this ?